# Facing 404 error with simple Spring MVC project

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I am trying to do a simple example with Spring MVC. Every code seems to be fine for me, but still getting 404 error.Here is my code, can u please help me why I am getting this error?

web.xml :

```
       <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

<display-name>Demo</display-name>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>hello.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Demo</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Demo</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/Demo-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Demo-servlet.xml(Dispatcher Servlet):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd ">

<mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.Demo" />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
</beans>
```

hello.jsp :

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

<html lang="en">
 <head>
 </head>
<body>
<h1>Gradle - Spring MVC Hello World</h1>
 <h2>Hello ${name}</h2>
 </body>
 </html>
```

HomeController.java:

```
 package com.Demo;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HomeController{

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String printHello(ModelMap model) {
   model.addAttribute("name", "Hello Spring MVC Framework!");
   return "hello";
 }
}
```

Please help me to solve this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the url that leads to 404

Answer (score 0):

Change your web.xml to this:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Demo</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Change your Controller to this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/demo")
public class HomeController
```

Now open a browser and invoke your Controller using this: ://demo.htm

During development, its good if you enable the Spring debug logs. Atleast till you get hold of the framework. They provide valuable information

Comment: thanks for ur response. But I dont think error is with the url-pattern. Because use of '/' means, it handles all kind of url pattern not only particular .htm or .jsp. And regarding the debug logs, my controller itself is not called, then how can I get any logs for the particular funtion.

Comment: I never said it does not work. Giving / to the URL pattern makes all the requests go through your RequestDispatcher. Including your static resources. So its a strong convention followed in Spring framework to either give a prefix (.htm or something else) or define your URLs in depth like /demo/create instead of just /. Remember, even before the call comes  to your controller, there are bunch of Filters, Interceptors, Classes that get invoked when you are in Spring and each of these components have some useful information to log. BTW, by Request Dispatcher i meant DispatcherServlet

Comment: At the least, you can define your Controller as @Controller
@RequestMapping("/home")
public class HomeController and invoke it http://<HOST>:<PORT>/<CONTEXT>/home